# Apache Won't Start, SVN unable to connect

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, svn-server

I am unable to connect to the SVN server.

It has become apparent that this is because Apache won't start.

On the server, Commit won't work, Import won't work, Repo browser won't work. On my local disk, all of those things work just fine with a local repository defined

Here are two examples of evidence that I get when I try any of those (using Windows Shell Extention and TortoiseSVN)

When I try to open the repo browser, I wait a long time; 2 mintues, maybe 3, maybe 5, after which I get this message...

```
 Unable to connect to a respository at URL "http://123.456.789.100/svn/etc"
```

We tracked this down to the Apache Server, which has stopped.

Any attempt to restart it results in...

```
 service specific error: 1
```

Found [this page](http://netheadaches.wordpress.com/2007/10/08/apache-not-starting-win32-apache2-service-terminated-with-service-specific-error-1-0x1/) on the internet which says that "...*It happens because apache tries to access a file in a folder which doesn't  exist*..."

Now, (1) Is that claim true ? (2) If so, then how do I determine which file or folder is expected but non-existant ?

Update, edit, request was made to remove screen shots and in their place include contents of httpd.conf file that are related to svn. Here they are.

```
 #
 ServerRoot "C:/Apache2-2"

 # Old name was...
 # ServerName 192.168.158.50

 ##  2013-APR-22
 ##
 ##  Joe70 changed the server name
 ##
 ##

 ServerName 192.168.183.50


 ##  2013-APR-22
 ##
 ##  The Old Listen Command was..
 ##
 ##   Listen 192.168.158.50:80
 ##
 ##  Joe70 changed it to this...
 ##
 ##

 Listen 192.168.183.50:80


 #Subversion Modules
 LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
 #LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so - commented by Joe90
 #LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so - commented by Joe90
 # removed comments for below two directives and changed to C:/ instead of C:\ - by Joe90
 LoadModule dav_svn_module C:/Subversion/bin/mod_dav_svn.so
 LoadModule authz_svn_module C:/Subversion/bin/mod_authz_svn.so

 #location of svn repo 
 <Location /svn>
         DAV svn
         SVNParentPath C:/svn
        # Changed from C:\svn to C:/svn - by Joe90
        SVNListParentPath on
    #SVNIndexXSLT "/svnindex.xsl"  
         AuthType Basic
         AuthName "Our Subversion repository"
         AuthUserFile passwd
         #AuthzSVNAccessFile svnaccessfile
         #changed from Require valid-user to: (by Joe80)
    Require valid-user
 </Location>


 #use virtual hosts
 NameVirtualHost *
```

Comment: 1. Show config of SVN-related part from your httpd.conf 2. These screenshots are useless wasted space here

Comment: I'd ask to add the error_log as well. Does it show anything interesting? Have you run netstat to see if anything else is running on that port?

Comment: @RichHomolka  No, Error log shows no activity, even though I can generate the error here and now today. I am totally confused by that observation

Comment: @RichHomolka, I just looked in the "logs/" folder, and all files appear to be untouched for more than a year.